# getting a java.io.Serializable from Option[..] in Scala

Tags: scala, null, scala-option

(just started with Scala a few weeks ago, so bear with me)

Reading/trying out this little article here, ran into some surprises

http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html

After defining a case class User as described:

```
case class User(
  id: Int,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  age: Int,
  gender: Option[String])

object UserRepository {
  private val users = Map(1 -> User(1, "John", "Doe", 32, Some("male")),
                          2 -> User(2, "Johanna", "Doe", 30, None))
  def findById(id: Int): Option[User] = users.get(id)
  def findAll = users.values
}
```

, here are the gets I observe:

```
> scala> UserRepository.findById(1)
> res34: Option[User] = Some(User(1,John,Doe,32,Some(male)))
> 
> scala> UserRepository.findById(1).get
> res35: User = User(1,John,Doe,32,Some(male))
> 
> scala> UserRepository.findById(1).getOrElse("N/A")
> res36: java.io.Serializable = User(1,John,Doe,32,Some(male))
>
> scala> UserRepository.findById(3).getOrElse("N/A")
> res37: java.io.Serializable = N/A
```

The first two are what I expected, but the second two aren't; both the case of existing and non-existing Users. Why java.io.Serializable, all of the sudden?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To understand this you have to understand what is `getOrElse`

```
final def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B
```

`getOrElse` is defined on `Option`. `Option` can be `Some(value)` or `None`.

`getOrElse` returns `default` when `option` is `none`

`val map = Map(1 -> 2)`

`map.get(1)` returns `option`

```
scala> Some(1).getOrElse(2)
res3: Int = 1

scala> Some(1).getOrElse("Hello")
res4: Any = 1


scala> case class User(name: String)
defined class User

scala> (None: Option[User]).getOrElse("a")
res12: java.io.Serializable = a

scala> (None: Option[User]).getOrElse(1)
res7: Any = 1
```

Coming to the point

`Some(a).getOrElse(b)`

if `a` and `b` are of same type then resultant type will be `a` type or `b` type

if `a` and `b` are `not` of same type then resultant type will be nearest common super type which is `java.io.Serializable` in your case.

Note that

1) nearest common super type for `User` and String is Serializable

2) nearest common super type for `User` and Int is Any

Comment: lo, this is _exactly_ what I thought of after asking the question. I was expecting it to be 'Any', though, just as in your example of 'Some(1).getOrElse("Hello"), but I suppose it falls back on Java class hierarchy, eh?

Comment: @alexakarpov because nearest common super type for User and string is Serializable